# How to detect COM+ API?

Tags: windows, winapi, com+

Windows has a touchpad feature: precision touchpad. This makes it possible to use three-fingers swipe or four-fingers swipe to change the desktop or call Task View.

I need to turn off this feature programmatically. It's possible using the registry, but that requires a reboot or logout-login, then explorer.exe will get the new settings.

But, if I turn off the swipe behaviour manually using System Settings, explorer.exe will update immediately.

I've checked this way using Process Monitor, and found that when I'm making changes to swipe behaviour in System Settings, explorer.exe starts reading the registry values about this. I consider, System Settings can notify explorer.exe using COM+ API, so I want to use it. But, I know nothing about the available methods.

1. How can I detect COM+ usage?
2. Is there any way to get API information from an exe file? The GUID of the COM+ API and methods.

Comment: *"The latest Windows got a new touchpad feature: precision touchpad."* - The precision touchpad was introduced in Windows 8.1 more than a decade ago. Might want to remove that part unless getting people confused is part of your mission.

Comment: I don't know this for a fact, but it seems more likely to me that the change in system settings triggers some sort of broadcast message - one that Explorer is listening for. You may want to take a look with Spy++, or similar, to see if you can see something going on when changing that setting.

Comment: I tried to broadcast a message using SendMessage from WinApi about updating settings, but explorer.exe doesn't react on that

Comment: Then you probably used the wrong broadcast message. Did you actually monitor the system, like 500 suggested? What makes you think System Settings is using COM+ to communicate with Explorer in the first place? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Using Process Monitor, I found the ReqQueryValue event for swipe settings from explorer.exe, next - I've checked the call stack, it has rpcrt4.dll mention and combase.dll

Using x64dbg I tried to debug SystemSettings.exe, so I found the COM+ call inside using combase.dll